# Program type already present: com.google.common.annotations.GwtCompatible

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm getting the following error when building my android project :

> Program type already present:
>   com.google.common.annotations.GwtCompatible Message{kind=ERROR,
>   text=Program type already present:
>   com.google.common.annotations.GwtCompatible, sources=[Unknown source
>   file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

gradle file :

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.www.www"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

            // multi-dex support (When your app and the libraries it references exceed 65,536 methods)
            multiDexEnabled true
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
        packagingOptions {
            exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
            exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
            exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
            exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
            exclude 'META-INF/INDEX.LIST'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        // multi-dex support (When your app and the libraries it references exceed 65,536 methods)
        implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'


        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


        //this is for the google "text recognizer"
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:15.0.2'
        implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-customsearch:v1-rev63-1.23.0'


        //for firebase database connection
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
        //implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
        // for firebase authentication
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'


        // for Google Natural Language Processing (part of google cloud services)
        implementation ('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-language:1.31.0')
              //  {
              //      exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
              //  }

    }


    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The following resolves THAT issue :

```
implementation ('com.google.cloud:google-cloud-language:1.31.0') { 
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava'
}
```

But then I am missing guava functions, because the following error will be thrown at runtime :

> Didn't find class "com.google.common.base.MoreObjects"
>
> Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: 
>   Lcom/google/common/base/MoreObjects;

When I run the following code : 
   public void testSomething(View view){

```
    // Instantiate the Language client com.google.cloud.language.v1.LanguageServiceClient
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("www.json");

            GoogleCredentials googleCredential = GoogleCredentials.fromStream(inputStream);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG,e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I'm going in circles here. I'm desperate to find the answer.
I have checked other questions/topics, no answers that help me.

Comment: Had you solved issue?

Answer (score 0):

I solved same problem by making below changes:

```
implementation ('com.google.apis:google-api-services-drive:v2-rev105-1.17.0-rc'){
    exclude module: 'guava-jdk5'
}
implementation ('com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.20.0'){
    exclude module: 'guava-jdk5'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change Gradles To This :

```js
implementation 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-vision:v1-rev369-1.23.0'  exclude module: 'guava-jdk5'
    implementation 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.23.0' exclude module: 'guava-jdk5' exclude module: 'httpclient'
    implementation 'com.google.http-client:google-http-client-gson:1.23.0' exclude module: 'httpclient'
```

This Worked For Me